# Flutter: Error When Passing Data With ProxyProvider

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I'm trying to build an app similar to a converter website where you need to put a link into the text field but instead of convert it, you can only see the info. I use ProxyProvider to connect the 2 providers. I followed this tutorial(https://dev.to/paulhalliday/how-to-use-proxyprovider-with-flutter-3ifo) on how to use ProxyProvider and get an error.
This is the code.
-main.dart

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        textTheme: ThemeData.light().textTheme.copyWith(
              headline1: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              headline2: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16.0,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              bodyText1: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              bodyText2: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
      ),
      title: 'ID',
      home: MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          Provider(
            create: (context) => InputService(),
          ),
          ProxyProvider<InputService, Future<CoreData>>(
            update: (context, InputService inputService,
                    Future<CoreData> questionsService) =>
                QuestionsService().fetchQuestion(inputService),
          ),
        ],
        child: UserInput(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

-the TextField code

```
class UserInput extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ScreenConfig().init(context);
    final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();


    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
        color: Colors.blueAccent,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Enter ID here',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: screenHeight(0.05),),
            TextField(
              controller: _controller,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'ID',
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                filled: true,
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text(
                'Enter',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
              ),
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),),
              color: Colors.lightBlue,
              onPressed: () {
                GetInput(userInput: _controller.text);
                print(GetInput(userInput: _controller.text));
                Provider.of<InputService>(context, listen: false);
                Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

-Where the JSON file is displayed

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future<CoreData> question = Provider.of<Future<CoreData>>(context);

    return FutureProvider(
          create: (BuildContext context) => question,
          child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
        body: question == null
            ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
            : CustomScrollView(
                slivers: [
                  CustomAppBar(),
                  CustomList(),
                ],
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

-The Provider for getting user input

```
class GetInput {

  String userInput;

  GetInput({@required this.userInput}); 
}

class InputService {
  GetInput getInput;
}
```

-The provider to serialize the JSON file of the link

```
class QuestionsService {

  Future<CoreData> fetchQuestion(InputService inputService) async {
    final response = await http.get(inputService.getInput.userInput);
    var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
    CoreData parsedQuestions = CoreData.fromJson(jsonResponse);

    return parsedQuestions;
  }
}
```

-The error message

````
I/flutter (21927): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (21927): The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building HomePage(dirty):
I/flutter (21927): Error: Could not find the correct Provider<Future<CoreData>> above this HomePage Widget
I/flutter (21927):
I/flutter (21927): This likely happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
I/flutter (21927): of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:
I/flutter (21927):
I/flutter (21927): - The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.
I/flutter (21927):
I/flutter (21927):   Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
I/flutter (21927):   other routes will not be able to access that provider.
I/flutter (21927):
I/flutter (21927): - You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.
I/flutter (21927):
I/flutter (21927):   Make sure that HomePage is under your MultiProvider/Provider<Future<CoreData>>.
I/flutter (21927):   This usually happen when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.
I/flutter (21927):
I/flutter (21927):   For example, instead of:
I/flutter (21927):
I/flutter (21927):   ```
I/flutter (21927):   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
I/flutter (21927):     return Provider<Example>(
I/flutter (21927):       create: (_) => Example(),
I/flutter (21927):       // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
I/flutter (21927):       // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
I/flutter (21927):       child: Text(context.watch<Example>()),
I/flutter (21927):     ),
I/flutter (21927):   }
I/flutter (21927):   ```
I/flutter (21927):
I/flutter (21927):   consider using `builder` like so:
I/flutter (21927):
I/flutter (21927):   ```
I/flutter (21927):   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
I/flutter (21927):     return Provider<Example>(
I/flutter (21927):       create: (_) => Example(),
I/flutter (21927):       // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
I/flutter (21927):       builder: (context) {
I/flutter (21927):         // No longer throws
I/flutter (21927):         return Text(context.watch<Example>()),
I/flutter (21927):       }
I/flutter (21927):     ),
I/flutter (21927):   }
I/flutter (21927):   ```
I/flutter (21927):
I/flutter (21927): If none of these solutions work, consider asking for help on StackOverflow:
I/flutter (21927): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter
I/flutter (21927):
I/flutter (21927): The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter (21927):   HomePage
I/flutter (21927):   file:///C:/Users/bryan/source/repos/Flutter%20Projects/testing/quizizz_cheat/lib/screens/user_input.dart:52:92
I/flutter (21927):
I/flutter (21927): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (21927): #0      Provider._inheritedElementOf (package:provider/src/provider.dart:309:7)
I/flutter (21927): #1      Provider.of (package:provider/src/provider.dart:261:30)
I/flutter (21927): #2      HomePage.build (package:quiz/screens/home.dart:9:42)
I/flutter (21927): #3      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4644:28)
I/flutter (21927): #4      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4570:15)
I/flutter (21927): #5      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4286:5)
I/flutter (21927): #6      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4549:5)
I/flutter (21927): #7      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4544:5)
I/flutter (21927): ...     Normal element mounting (132 frames)
I/flutter (21927): #139    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3512:14)
I/flutter (21927): #140    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3270:18)
I/flutter (21927): #141    RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5648:32)
I/flutter (21927): #142    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6189:17)
I/flutter (21927): #143    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3257:15)
I/flutter (21927): #144    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4595:16)
I/flutter (21927): #145    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4743:11)
I/flutter (21927): #146    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4286:5)
I/flutter (21927): #147    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4775:5)
I/flutter (21927): #148    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3257:15)
I/flutter (21927): #149    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4595:16)
I/flutter (21927): #150    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4286:5)
I/flutter (21927): #151    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4930:5)
I/flutter (21927): #152    _InheritedNotifierElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/inherited_notifier.dart:183:11)
I/flutter (21927): #153    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3257:15)
I/flutter (21927): #154    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6068:14)
I/flutter (21927): #155    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3257:15)
I/flutter (21927): #156    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4595:16)
I/flutter (21927): #157    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4743:11)
I/flutter (21927): #158    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4286:5)
I/flutter (21927): #159    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4775:5)
I/flutter (21927): #160    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3257:15)
I/flutter (21927): #161    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6068:14)
I/flutter (21927): #162    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3257:15)
I/flutter (21927): #163    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6068:14)
I/flutter (21927): #164    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3257:15)
I/flutter (21927): #165    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4595:16)
I/flutter (21927): #166    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4286:5)
I/flutter (21927): #167    StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4651:5)
I/flutter (21927): #168    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3257:15)
I/flutter (21927): #169    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4595:16)
I/flutter (21927): #170    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4286:5)
I/flutter (21927): #171    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4930:5)
I/flutter (21927): #172    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3257:15)
I/flutter (21927): #173    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4595:16)
I/flutter (21927): #174    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4743:11)
I/flutter (21927): #175    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4286:5)
I/flutter (21927): #176    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2673:33)
I/flutter (21927): #177    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:913:20)
I/flutter (21927): #178    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:302:5)
I/flutter (21927): #179    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1117:15)
I/flutter (21927): #180    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1055:9)
I/flutter (21927): #181    SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:971:5)
I/flutter (21927): #185    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:251:10)
I/flutter (21927): #186    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:209:3)
I/flutter (21927): (elided 3 frames from dart:async)
I/flutter (21927): 
I/flutter (21927): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
````

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that Providers are "scoped". So if you insert a provider inside a route, then other routes will not be able to access that provider. You need to make the provider accessible to all the widgets that are using it. Instead of placing `MultiProvider` inside `MaterialApp`, you should move it up. (Place it above `MaterialApp`)
Try doing this instead:

```
MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          Provider(
            create: (context) => InputService(),
          ),
          ProxyProvider<InputService, Future<CoreData>>(
            update: (context, InputService inputService,
                    Future<CoreData> questionsService) =>
                QuestionsService().fetchQuestion(inputService),
          ),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(...
        ),
      ),
```